# MacBook Air sleep with external monitor attached

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I would like my MacBook Air running Yosemite to sleep once I close the lid, even if an external monitor is attached.

Before Yosemite this could be achieved with `sudo nvram boot-args=iog=0x0`. This has stopped working after the upgrade.

Is there another or a new way to achieve the effect I want?

Answer (score 1):

You have to disconnect it from power. Then it will sleep.
Seems like no other solution is found yet.

And your question seems to be a duplicate — [How to disable Clamshell mode in Yosemite?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152777/how-to-disable-clamshell-mode-in-yosemite)